# How to redirect a link using htaccess?

Tags: html, .net, .htaccess

I have two domains as follows:

1. http://www.sysmedac.com/
2. https://www.sysmedacmicrosoft.com/Index.html.

How do I redirect from the first domain to the second one using htacces?
Have used the following code:

```
<IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www.sysmedac.com/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.sysmedacmicrosoft.com/Index.html#!/$1 [R=301,L]
    Redirect 301 /contact https://www.sysmedacmicrosoft.com/#!/Contact
</IfModule>
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use-

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 https://www.old_url.com http://www.new_url.com/
#===========
Redirect 301 https://www.sysmedacmicrosoft.com/Index.html http://www.sysmedac.com/
```

or
if you want to remove index.html-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Used the ones which you gave me but it remains the same . Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: do you enabled rewrite module if not, use-  `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
then restart apache

Comment: Now the domain transfer is done but I want the domain name to be the same, it gets changed .

Comment: it's called domain forwarding not domain redirection. it can be done by domain registrar panel.

Answer (score -1):

You need to write below rule to Redirect from an index.html file to the main link.

Redirect /index.html /

This rule will redirect your http://www.sysmedac.com/index.html to http://www.sysmedac.com/.